# Tensorflow is not using the GPU for python_io library

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am really new to tensorflow and this might be a simple question. I was wondering what are the correct mechanism for assignment of the GPU devices in the code. 
Specifically I want to transfer this part of the code to the GPU:

```
tfr_opt = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.NONE)
            for lod in range(self.resolution_log2 - 1):
                tfr_file = self.tfr_prefix + '-r%02d.tfrecords' % (self.resolution_log2 - lod)
                self.tfr_writers.append(tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfr_file, tfr_opt))
```

But using line:

```
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
```

Doesn't seem to be helping and when I do nvidia-smi I am seeing that memory and GPU usage is 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to execute the below code and see which device it uses.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Place tensors on the GPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  print(c)
```

and then place the same "tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)" and try the code you have mentioned and see if it works.

It should log the device while executing the code.